# Running Hunspell in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, hunspell

I want to run Hunspell in all subdirectories and check all the markdown files in there.

Easy right?

So I wrote: `find ./ -type f -exec hunspell -l *.md {} \;`

When I run this command it shows much more than only the three test markdown files. What is wrong with this command?

PS:
`-l` means that Hunspell will only output the words that have a spelling error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look for only the `*.md` files,

```
find . -iname '*.md' -type f -exec hunspell -l {} \;
```

Since you are not looking for a certain file name pattern, passing `{}` like that to `hunspell` means every file.

Update: added the quotes to the initial answer

Comment: Thanks! That's close. But now it doesn't go through the md files in the subdirs

Comment: Interesting, apparently quotes are needed, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123440/why-is-my-find-not-recursive. Could you try with that?